# Couldn't add active class to a menu when visit default page

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, menu

I created a menu.

html part:

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="a.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="b.html">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="c.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And I want to add active class to menu based on url.

js part:

```
var pageurl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf('/')+1);

$('#menu a').each(function(){
    if($(this).attr('href') == pageurl || $(this).attr('href') == '') {
        $(this).addClass('onSelect');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('offSelect');
    }
});
```

It works fine when I click menu:

```
/* http://exmaple.com/b.html */

<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="a.html" class="offSelect">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="b.html" class="onSelect">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="c.html" class="offSelect">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

The problem is I've already set "Home" as my default page, but the first time when I visit the site, I couldn't add active class for "a.html":

```
/* http://exmaple.com */

<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="a.html" class="offSelect">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="b.html" class="offSelect">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="c.html" class="offSelect">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Is there something wrong in my js code?

Comment: Did you kept your `js`  in `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Yes!!

Comment: what will be the `pageurl` on first time page load? If it is `a.html` then above code should work!!

Comment: your URL looks like `http://exmaple.com` on default page, so your `pageurl` is `exmaple.com` here and you don't consider this case

Comment: Try adding `class="onSelect"` to the first `a` since `a.html` is default page, but then you need to take care of preserving it in `page load`

Comment: Put in in html directly <li><a href="a.html" class="onSelect">Home</a></li>

Comment: when first time page load, I use "alert(pageurl)" and saw empty value, the url is "http://exmaple.com", if I click Home in menu, "alert(pageurl)" shows a.html, and the url became "http://example.com/a.html"

Comment: then you should handle the empty string in your JS code

Comment: @Sergej I write `$(this).attr('href') == ''` in my js code, so it can't handle the empty string?

Comment: If I add `class="onSelect"` to the first `a` since `a.html` is default page, I have to write more code such as `removeClass("onSelect").addClass("offSelect")` when I click another menu, is it the best way for menu?

Comment: this would handle `<a href="" class="offSelect">Home</a>` so an empty href, not an empty `pageurl`

Comment: @Sergej Thx, I think I got the point.